# How to edit this file using grep or using cat or using vim or using another tool?

Tags: vim, sed, grep, cat

One of my elder brother who is studying in Statistics. Now, he is writing his thesis paper in [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX). Almost all contents are written for the paper. And he took 5 number after point(e.g. 5.55534) for each value those are used for his calculation. But, at the last time his instructor said to change those to 3 number after point(e.g. 5.555) which falls my brother in trouble. Finding and correcting those manually is not easy. So, he told me to help.

I believe there is also a easy solution which is know to me. The snapshot of a portion of the thesis looks like-

```
      &se($\hat\beta_1$)&0.35581&0.35573&0.35573\\
                         &mse($\hat\beta_1$)&.12945&.12947&.12947\\
   \addlinespace
                         &$\hat\beta_2$&0.03329&0.03331&0.03331 \\
                          &se($\hat\beta_2$)&0.01593&0.01592&0.01591\\
                          &mse($\hat\beta_2$)&.000265&.000264&.000264 \\

                         \midrule
  {n=100} & $\hat\beta_1$&-.52006&-.52001&-.51946\\
                        &se($\hat\beta_1$)&.22819&.22814&.22795\\
                        &mse($\hat\beta_1$)&.05247&.05244&.05234\\
   \addlinespace
                         &$\hat\beta_2$&0.03134&0.03134&0.03133 \\
                         &se($\hat\beta_2$)&0.00979&0.00979&0.00979\\
                         &mse($\hat\beta_2$)&.000098&.000098&.000098
```

I want -

```
      &se($\hat\beta_1$)&0.355&0.355&0.355\\
                         &mse($\hat\beta_1$)&.129&.129&.129\\
......................................................................
........................................................................
........................................................................
```

> Note: Don't feel boring for the syntax(These are LaTeX syntax).

If anybody has solution or suggestion, please provide. Thank you.

Comment: [tag:perl], [tag:vim], [tag:awk], [tag:sed] ...? Which is it? I removed all tags except [tag:sed], since that has an upvoted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sed:

```
$ sed 's/\(\.[0-9]\{3\}\)[0-9]*/\1/g' file
      &se($\hat\beta_1$)&0.355&0.355&0.355\\
                         &mse($\hat\beta_1$)&.129&.129&.129\\
```

ie. replace period starting numeric strings with at least 3 numbers with the leading period and three first numbers.

Comment: It's customary to comment when downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command in `vim`:

```
:%s/\.\d\{3}\zs\d\+//g
```

#### Explanation:

`:` entering command-mode

`%` is the range of all lines of the file

`s` substitution command

`\.\d\{3}\zs\d\+` pattern you would like to change

- `\.` literal point (.)
- `\d\{3}` match 3 consecutive digits
- `\zs` start substitution from here
- `\d\+` one or more digits

`g` Replace all occurrences in the line

---

Concerning `grep` and `cat` they have nothing to do with replacing text. These commands are only for searching and printing contents of files.

Instead, what you are looking is **substitution** there are lots of commands in Linux that can do that mainly `sed`, `perl`, `awk`, `ex` etc.

Comment: Thanks. It is helpful because I use vim.

Comment: If you will explain your answer, it is helpful for another.

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal I have edited my answer. Hope it helps !